# XLSX writer: write images with nested loop

Tags: python, nested-loops, xlsxwriter

I have have a list with urls to images, and like to insert each image into a new row of an xlsx file (so image 1 in row 1, image 2 in row 2, etc).

But something is going very wrong with my nested loop. In my current code, each image is being inserted into each row (so image 1, 2, and 3 in row 1, and so on). I tried many things with this nested loop, but can't get my head around it. Below you find the code I came up so far. Any help is much appreciated!

```
import xlsxwriter
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen

urls = ['http://resizing.flixster.com/M_qLa6b79ltj089zlncMGyVd7-0=/128x128/v1.YzszMDExO2o7MTg1ODU7MjA0ODs4NzI7ODcy',
 'http://resizing.flixster.com/RiZZxnhbXJxoVeEiiegBPtAMJYI=/128x128/v1.YzszNzAzO2o7MTg1ODU7MjA0ODszMDA7MzAw',
 'http://resizing.flixster.com/_5Pu-PGT3sdzRa0aQHiP8AGGmSI=/128x128/v1.YzszNjk4O2o7MTg1ODU7MjA0ODszMDA7MzAw']

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet1')

worksheet.write('A1', 'image critic')
for url in urls:
    for row in range(1,len(urls)+1):    
        image_data = BytesIO(urlopen(url).read())
        worksheet.insert_image(f'A{row}', url[row-1], {'image_data': image_data})
workbook.close()
```

For those who are curious, these image urls refer to film critics scraped from Rottentomatoes.com

Comment: `something is going very wrong with my nested loop` – what's the problem?

Comment: @Alderven I updated my post with more details on what went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate` to get `row` value for each URL:

```
import xlsxwriter
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen

urls = ['http://resizing.flixster.com/M_qLa6b79ltj089zlncMGyVd7-0=/128x128/v1.YzszMDExO2o7MTg1ODU7MjA0ODs4NzI7ODcy',
        'http://resizing.flixster.com/RiZZxnhbXJxoVeEiiegBPtAMJYI=/128x128/v1.YzszNzAzO2o7MTg1ODU7MjA0ODszMDA7MzAw',
        'http://resizing.flixster.com/_5Pu-PGT3sdzRa0aQHiP8AGGmSI=/128x128/v1.YzszNjk4O2o7MTg1ODU7MjA0ODszMDA7MzAw']

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet1')

worksheet.write('A1', 'image critic')
for row, url in enumerate(urls):
    image_data = BytesIO(urlopen(url).read())
    worksheet.insert_image(f'A{row+1}', url, {'image_data': image_data})
workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks that is amazing. The missing part in my scraper :) I will do some more research on this enumerate function. It seems very useful.